# How to specify intermediate certificates for s_client and s_server?

Tags: openssl, certificate

`openssl verify` has an `-untrusted` option to specify a chain of intermediate certificates that stand between

- a root CA certificate, which are specified with the `-CAfile` or `-CApath` option
- and a leaf certificate to be verified, which are given as the last arguments

Does anyone know how we specify the intermediate cert chain for the `openssl s_client` and the `openssl s_server` commands? The man pages do not say anything about it unfortunately.

It seems that if the intermediate chain is included in the file passed to the `-cert` option together with the client or server certificate, it does not work, only the first certificate is read from that file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Meta: this isn't really a programming or development question. It might belong instead on superuser or maybe security.SX.

For OpenSSL versions 1.1.0 (released 2016-08) up, you can provide the (exact) intermediate/chain cert(s) in a file using `-cert_chain` and/or you can specify `-build_chain` and use `-chainCAfile` and/or `-chainCApath` from which the needed cert(s) are selected, similar to the way `-CAfile` and `-CApath` are traditionally used. However, these aren't *documented* in 1.1.0, only 1.1.1 (2018-09); see those man pages if you have them installed, or on the web for [s_client](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/s_client.html) and [s_server](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/s_server.html).

For lower versions, you need a kludge: `-CAfile` and `-CApath` which nominally supply the truststore for verifying the *peer* cert are *also* used (implicitly) to complete your *own* (self) chain. Note non-root CA certs in the truststore are used to build chains both for sending and verification (receiving), but not as verification *anchors* in these versions, so including them never changes what peer certs are actually accepted as valid. (In 1.1.0 and 1.1.1 they still are not anchors by default, but are if you specify `-partial_chain`.)

Comment: Very clear answer, thank you! Sounds like you know the code inside out. Cant wait to try!